# How to sort by a filter using two different queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm building a forum and am trying to sort threads by the last reply date. So when someone visits the homepage and clicks sort by "Reply" it will sort the threads by the most recent reply. I'm having trouble doing this with a switch order though. I tried using:

```
var threads = from s in db.Forum
              where s.ReplyId==0
              select s;
var Replies = (from s in db.Forum
                         where s.ReplyId != 0
                         select s).OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated);
switch (sortOrder)
{
    default:
         threads = threads.OrderByDescending(s => Replies.Where(i => i.ReplyId == threads.Where(t=> t.Id==i.ReplyId).FirstOrDefault().Id).FirstOrDefault().DateCreated);
         break;
}
```

And I get a run time error saying "A cycle was detected".

The threads query grabs all posts that have a ReplyId of 0 or in other words every post that is considered a thread. The Replies grabs all posts that aren't equal to 0 or in other words all posts that are replies to the threads.

Can anyone show me an alternative way to sort the threads by recent replies? Both replies and threads use the same model, so it makes it challenging.

Comment: your question is confusing. I've read 3 times and could not get the difference between "sort threads by the last reply date" vs "sort the threads by the most recent reply". Maybe if you put the task in different way, you'll get the answer yourself.

Comment: So I want to display the most recent threads based on their replies. So if thread1 was replied to I want thread1 at the top of the list, because it's the thread with the most recent activity. Does that make since?

Comment: Can you just get a list of most recent replies from DB, join them to threads and display these threads?

Comment: Ok, I'm even more confused now. What is the difference between `thread` and `reply`? Can you post your models and their relation?

Comment: They use the same model. They are considered the same thing except replies don't have a title. A thread is the first post of the actual thread and the replies are the replies for that thread.

Comment: OK. Same approach is still valid. Get the latest replies and build the thread from the bottom-up.

Comment: Could you show me with some code snippets?

Comment: Sorry, can't. I'm not sure how your objects are linked together. What I just realised is that you should make life easier for yourself and have 2 different models for `Thread` and `Reply`. All the replies live within the Thread. And your problems will go away. Otherwise you are in some sort of recursion when you need to build a ll replies into a thread.

Answer (score 0):

> used DISTINCT() function in linq query  but this function is used only one filed in table